# loopback save related hasmany models in single request

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two models that are related through a hasMany relationship.

`Customer` hasMany `CustomerPhones`

When creating a new `Customer`, I would like to pass the related `CustomerPhones` as part a single request. This seems like a common need, if the approach I am looking to implement in wrong, what is the preferred way of doing this?

This is the url for creating a customer: `POST /api/Customers`

The request for above url would be **req.body**

```
{
  "name": "Foo",
  "customerPhones": [
    { "phoneNumber": "8085551234" },
    { "phoneNumber": "8085554567" }
  ]
}
```

Loopback models configurations:

**Customer.json**

```
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "base": "User",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "customerPhones": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "CustomerPhone",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
}
```

**CustomerPhone.json**

```
{
  "name": "CustomerPhone",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "phoneNumber": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "customerId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but here it what I ended up doing. I created a new RemoteMethod named createNew on Customer. Within this new remote method I use the methods added through the model relationships.

```
Customer.createNew = function (data) {
  var newCustomerId;
  var customerPhones = null;

  if (data.customerPhones && data.customerPhones.length) {
    customerPhones = data.customerPhones;
  }

  return Customer
    .create(data)
    .then(function createCustomerPhones (customer) {
      newCustomerId = customer.id;
      if (customerPhones) {
        customer.customerPhones.create(customerPhones);
      }
    })
    .then(function fetchNewCustomerIncludeRelated () {
      return Customer
        .findById(newCustomerId, {
          include: [ 'customerPhones' ]
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return err;
    });
};
```

To make this a bit safer I will need to wrap it in a transaction. I was hoping to use the base CRUD methods, but this solution if fairly clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NoSQL database connector, then you could ignore another `CustomerPhone` model and add the `customerPhones` property as an array in the `Customer` model.

Else for SQL database connector, you could create a remote method that performs both `POST /api/Customers` and `POST /api/Customers/id/CustomerPhones` together. For multiple phone numbers you could iterate the `customerPhones` field in the **req.body** and perform `POST /api/Customers/id/CustomerPhones` everytime.

Comment: I am using SQL. What you are suggesting is what I basically ended up doing. I made a new RemoteMethod named create.

Comment: I think there is no other way of doing this as `CustomerPhones` is dependent on the `Customer` object for the `belongsTo` relation to work.

Answer (score 0):

If this could be any help, instead of iterating you can insert the numbers in a single step like this:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "[{
        \"number\": \"1000\",
        \"type\": \"mobile\",
        \"customerId\": 1
    }, {
        \"number\": \"1004\",
        \"type\": \"home\",
        \"customerId\": 1
    }, {
        \"number\": \"1400\",
        \"type\": \"work\",
        \"customerId\": 1
    }]" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/customers/1/phones"
```

Comment: I am wanting to basically create a new Customer and new Phones in the same call. Because the Customer does not yet exist I can not use Customer/:id/Phones. The customerId is not know yet.

Comment: Down voted as it says it wants to create customer & phones in one request

Comment: @Anoop.P.A wake up due and read question again.It says it wants to do 2 data entries in 1 request.And in your answer ,customer data entry is already done and you are updating it with second request.So yours is wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is still not implemented by loopback. Please refer to this issue https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/846.